# Why we need call or apply method in javascript, when we can directly call the method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, apply, call

Why do we use Call or Apply method in java script? What is the major difference between normal method invocation and using Call/Apply apart from the differences of parameters being sent to invoke the method? If you could explain with a scenario please ?

Answer (score 2):

It can be helpful when dealing with objects, I suggest you reading these two guides, they explain it very well:

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_call.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_apply.asp

Answer (score 2):

As you may know, functions are the first-class citizens in JavaScript. It means that you can pass them as arguments to other functions.

In some cases you're dealing with `methods` which rely on a context. For example:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const getRect = button.getBoundingClientRect;

getRect(); // TypeError...

// You have to pass a context fo that function
getRect.call(button);
```

*There are some other functions to pass a context. Please take a look on `apply`, `bind`, `call`...*

Another great example of using `call` and `apply` is **monkey-patching**:

```js
// Save the original console.log() method
var log = console.log;

console.log = function() {
   // Invoke the original method with an additional parameter
   log.apply(console, [(new Date()).toString()].concat(arguments));
};
```

Kyle Simpson has a great explanation in his series [**You don't know JS**](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md)

Answer (score 1):

I can give you two examples that will explain why it is important. Let's say you have a class shown below:

```js
class MyClass {
  myProp = 'Hello World';
  myMethod() {
    console.log(this.myProp);
  }
}
```

Let's assume you want to call `myMethod` on a button click event. This is what you'll do:

```js
const myInstance = new MyClass();
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', myInstance.myMethod);
```

Now there is a problem: With `addEventListener` the execution context changes and `this` refers to the element instead of class instance (which does not have `myProp` property on it). How do I change it back? In such a scenario you can use `bind`.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', myInstance.myMethod.bind(myInstance));
```

This essentially changes the reference back to the class. This is just one example. There can be numerous examples where you want to change the current execution context of a method. Let's take another example:

Let's assume there is a third party function which requires access to some class members.

Third party function requires target instance's `name` and `lastname` properties.

```js
function getFullName() {
  return this.name + ' ' + this.lastname;
}
```

If you execute this method without `call` or `apply`, the method assumes the current instance on which this function exists (in this case it is window), and search the properties on current object. But there can be requirements where you might wanna change this behavior. Let's say you have class which provides the `name` and `lastname` properties, and you wanna leverage the functionality of this method. This is what you can do:

```js
class MyName {
  name = 'Tom';
  lastname = 'Hanks';
}

getFullName.apply(new MyName()); // --> 'Tom Hanks'
```

So you see how `call` and `apply` are helpful. You can refer to Zer0's answer to learn more about `call`, `apply` and `bind`.

Answer (score 1):

It's about **this** context in apply vs call. Apply you can pass args in an array.

Answer (score 1):

you can also access functions with the same name from different objects by it, for example toString() or whatever you like:

```
class MyObject {
    constructor(operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }
    
    calculate(a, b) {
        switch(this.operator) {
            case '+': return a + b;
            case '-': return a - b;
            case '*': return a * b;
            case '/': return a / b;
        }
    }
}

const operators = [
    new MyObject('+'),
    new MyObject('-'),
    new MyObject('*')
];
for (const op of operators) {
    const func = op['calculate'];
    console.log(func.call(op, 1, 1));
}
```